# Ant zipfileset not including all files

Tags: java, ant

I'm trying to build my project with Ant and also generating a .zip file, but it seems that the zipfileset instruction doesn't work in my build.xml:

```
<target name="MyService" description="Create installation zip" depends="all">
  <mkdir dir="myservice\bin\"/>
  <delete file="myservice\bin\MyService.zip"/>
  <zip destfile="myservice\bin\MyService.zip">
    <fileset dir="." includes="GUI.jar"/>
    <zipfileset includes="prunsrv.exe" src="myservice\lib\commons-daemon-1.0.15-bin-windows.zip"/>
  </zip>
  <delete file="myservice\bin\MyService64.zip"/>
  <zip destfile="myservice\bin\MyService64.zip">
    <fileset dir="." includes="GUI.jar"/>
    <zipfileset fullpath="prunsrv.exe" includes="amd64\prunsrv.exe" src="myservice\lib\commons-daemon-1.0.15-bin-windows.zip"/>
  </zip>
</target>
```

The zip files was created, but prunsrv.exe was not incuded in the zip.

**System info**
Win7 Pro sp1
4Gb RAM
OS 64 bit

**System variable set**
ANT_OPTS=-Xmx1024m

**Java and Ant version**
java version "1.6.0_06"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_06-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 10.0-b22, mixed mode, sharing)

Apache Ant version 1.7.1 compiled on June 27 2008

Solutions?
Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Which Zip file doesn't contain `prunsrv.exe`: `MyService.zip`, `MyService64.zip`, or both? Also, please try running `ant -debug` and posting the results.

Comment: Thank you Chad, I found the solution trying -debug. The problem is the commons-daemon-1.0.15-bin-windows.zip, that is not recognized as "well formed". I've re-zip it and the problem is solved. Thanks again!